# Extra space in front of each line

Tags: c, printf

```
for (day = 1; day <= 31; day++)
    {
        printf("%2d", day);

        if ((day + 1) % 7 > 0)
            printf(" ");
        else
            printf("\n ");
    }
```

When run this, I found that in each line, there will be one space.

How can I delete it?

Output of my code:

```
  S  M Tu  W Th  F  S
                 1  2
  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
 31
```

Comment: In else statement change `printf("\n ");` to `printf("\n");`

Comment: woo!!! Thanks a lot, I made a stupid mistake!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, change `printf ("\n ");` to `printf ("\n");` as mentioned in Aleksandar's comment.

Basically, in your case, you are going to a new line, and then printing a space. But your purpose is just to go to a new line. So you remove the space.